# Changing column value by finding substring in string values

Tags: python, pandas, substring, pandas-apply

I'm trying to change the values in a single column using pandas apply(). My function partially worked, but I'm stuck on how to fix this other half.

Data Column:

`County Name
 Riverside County
 San Diego County
 SanFrancisco County/city`

I'm trying to get rid of " County" so I'm left with just the name of the county. I successfully got rid of the " County" with the function but I'm having trouble removing the " County/city" from San Francisco.

Code:

```
def modify_county(countyname):
  if "/city" in countyname:
    return countyname.replace(" County/city","")
  return countyname.replace(" County","")

lfd["CountyName"] = lfd["CountyName"].apply(modify_county)
```

Output:

```
CountyName
Riverside
San Diego
San Francisco County/city
```

Is something wrong with the conditional in the function?

Comment: Why have an if statement at all? If "/city" isn't in the string, then countyname.replace(" County/city", "") just won't do anything

Comment: I copied your code and input and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative way. It works with the data you have provided.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['Riverside County', 'San Diego County', 'SanFrancisco County/city'])

res = s.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([w for w in x.split() if not 'County' in w]))

print(res)

# 0       Riverside
# 1       San Diego
# 2    SanFrancisco
# dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

@jpp's answer is the literal way of doing what you asked for. But in this case I would use [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) and some regex to substitute the entire thing in one go:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['Riverside County', 'San Diego County', 'SanFrancisco County/city'])

res = s.replace(' County(/city)?', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

@jpp, used suggestion to apply to entire column. Not sure if this is the best way, but it worked.

`lfd["CountyName"] = pd.Series(lfd["CountyName"])`

```
lfd["CountyName"] = lfd["CountyName"].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([w for w in x.split() if not 'County' in w]))
```